# How to set Foreground color stored in string variable in Java?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, colors

I am getting the colour from the database and the store that colour in string by using result set. Now I try to set foreground colour of button

```
String a="red";
jButton1.setForeground(Color.a);
```

But it shows that a symbol is not found

Comment: Java does not parse colors like that.  Don't forget, there are 16,777,216 possible RGB colors mixing the 256 shades of each that can be represented.  Try and name each of those!  Java does of course offer the [`Color` constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#field.summary) for a limited range of named colors, but unless you can match the string to a named color constant using reflection, the best bet is to maintain a map of colors for the string keys and use that to translate the DB string to a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to store the RGB string for the colors you are storing in the database.

example:

for red you can store something like "255,0,0"

and when you retrieve them back into a variable, parse these values into integers using comma as delimiter and then use the token values to reproduce the colors.

```
String colorFromDB = "255,0,0";
StringTokenizer cTokens = new StringTokenizer(colorFromDB, ",");
Color buttonColor = new Color(cTokens.nextToken(),cTokens.nextToken(),cTokens.nextToken());
```

Comment: Since DBs can store integers, groups of three integers and Java serialized objects such as a serialized `Color`, I don't really see the point of converting one `String` to another `String` ..

Answer (score 0):

i assume you want to get a Color object from the awt package, from String. The code above attpemts to acess variable a from class Color. there is no such visible field. To get color from String you need to call Color#getColor(String parameter);
Color Class documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html
Check out the methods and find the one you need.

Comment: i also try this     jButton1.setForeground(Color.getColor(a)); it don't show any error but it don't change colour to

Comment: *"Color#getColor(String parameter) .. Check out the methods and find the one you need."*  If you'd checked those docs you might have noticed mention that the string is intended to contain the **integer** form of a color.  It does not parse strings like `"red"` to a `Color`.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson and that beings me back to my post, I didn't mention getting a color by name but getting it using this method that takes as Param string :- ) and that's also why I linked to the docs, because at the time I did not have the time to explain that it needs the id and how to obtain it and blah blah blah :D